# Why abn divided for 89?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recent days I'm working on ABN (Australian business number), I tried to write a snippet to validate an ABN.

I curious about 89.
Why is 89 ? why not another number ? What I should call it number ?

```
class AbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  ABN_LENGTH = 11
  FACTOR_WEIGHTING = [10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19].freeze
  # Reference https://abr.business.gov.au/HelpAbnFormat.aspx
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless valid?(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'ABN is invalid')
    end
  end

  private

  def valid?(value)
    value = value.gsub(/\s+/, '')
    return false unless value.length == ABN_LENGTH

    sum = 0
    (0..10).each do |i|
      c = value[i, 1]
      digit = c.to_i - (i.zero? ? 1 : 0)
      sum += FACTOR_WEIGHTING[i] * digit
    end

    (sum % 89).zero?
  end
end
```

Thanks for any explanation!